# How to filter multiple Arrays with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to filter multiple arrays of Skills (they are coming from json file) (example below) and print out the candidate name + all skills

```
┌─────────┬───────────────────────┐
│ (index) │        Values         │
├─────────┼───────────────────────┤
│    0    │       'angular'       │
│    1    │         'css'         │
│    2    │      'bootstrap'      │
│    3    │      'react.js'       │
│    4    │        'rxjs'         │
│    5    │         'git'         │
│    6    │        'java'         │
│    7    │       'graphql'       │
│    8    │       'node.js'       │
│    9    │        'redux'        │
│   10    │        'json'         │
│   11    │        'html'         │
│   12    │         'sql'         │
│   13    │        'linux'        │
│   14    │      'gatsby.js'      │
│   15    │       'mongodb'       │
│   16    │     'javascript'      │
│   17    │         'php'         │
│   18    │        'ionic'        │
│   19    │ 'amazon web services' │
└─────────┴───────────────────────┘
```

but instead of all skills I'm just getting single values (1 skill/1 line) and the output looks in console looks like this:

> this guys knows javascript
> this guys knows nodejs
> this guys knows react
> this guys knows javascript

**But the goal is to have all skills in 1 line like this:**

> this guys knows javascript nodejs react

**input.json**

```
{
    "stackIncluded": [
    "nodejs",
    "javascript"
    ]
}
```

Here is a code of the function that I've written, **index.js**

```js
'use strict';
const curationInput = require('./curation-input.json');
const fileToCurate = require('./trlele.json');

async function curateStack() {
  const stackIncluded = curationInput.stackIncluded;
  fileToCurate.forEach(candidate => {
    candidate.folder.forEach(folder => {

      // get Arrays with all objects that including candidates skills
      const allSkills = folder.skills;

      // map Arrays with objects to Arrays with skills only
      const values = allSkills.map(item => item.value);

      // lowercase the values of skills
      const lowercaseSkills = values.map(skill => skill.toLowerCase());
      //console.table(lowercaseSkills)

      lowercaseSkills.forEach(skillsArray => {
        if (stackIncluded.includes(skillsArray)) {
          console.log('this guys knows', skillsArray);
        }
      });

    });
  });
}
```

Comment: `this guys knows` should be before the loop

Comment: Try creating a string in forEach() candidate where you append each() skill in skills array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the last part of your script

```js
let str = 'this guys knows '
lowercaseSkills.forEach(skillsArray => {
    if (stackIncluded.includes(skillsArray)) {
        str += skillsArray + ' ';
    }
});
console.log(str);
```

another way

```js
const skills = lowercaseSkills.filter(item => stackIncluded.includes(item));
console.log('this guys knows', skills.join(', ')]);
```